# Sharepoint Active directory permissions

Tags: 2013, permissions, sync, directory, userprofiles

I have a functioning Mysite with all user accounts added. I imported the accounts from active directory when I first constructed SharePoint. I have recently made changes in active directory to users and groups and I want to sync/import changes to SharePoint with out writing over the mysites section on SharePoint. Would my best option be to go to synchronization options under the user profile service and run one "SharePoint active directory import" and switch back to "use SharePoint profile synchronization" to continue things?

Comment: what changes you want to save. either ADI or User Profile Sync, once you import accounts from AD it will update in the SharePoint. So we want to know which settings you trying to save

Comment: I want what currently exits, but I have adjusted some groups (added/removed users) in active directory and I want to apply those changes to my sharepoint site so that I can refer to the active directory group/s when granting permissions instead of creating groups in sharepoint

Comment: when you run the Import /sync from AD, it will update all profiles and remove the users from sharepoint(if removed from AD) and also Add the user(if new in AD) and same with changes...there is no way to keep the information while running the sync

Comment: Okay, I have not removed any users, just added/removed users from groups...but all users still remain in the directory. Would an import/sync wipe all the personal mysite creations(including profile pics)? Would this be the best route to take or should I just create the groups in sharepoint even though best practice is creating them in AD

Comment: No No No....only way Profile or Mysite wiped out if you remove the user from AD and then run full sync. As long as ID remains in the AD without changing the SID, their will be no impact on user's mysite and profile

Comment: Okay, I am going to go ahead and run this "To use the light-weight Active Directory Import option (with some limitations - see documentation), select 'Use SharePoint Active Directory Import'." I should select users/groups correct?

Comment: yes, do you already have the user profile sync setup or not? You canot have both UPS and ADI

Comment: I have the user profile sync setup but is it normally net to "Use SharePoint Profile Synchronization". Would I have to delete my user profile service and recreate it for AS profile sync?

Comment: If you already have profile services configured then why you need ADI, just run the full sync

Comment: I have run the full sync rather than the incremental and the changes that I have made in active directory have not taken place on SharePoint. Any suggestions?